# How to set input box height in smart filter bar?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to change height for all input box in smart filter bar to smaller, is it possible without using CSS? In smart filter bar it is possible to change width, but not height, somebody has solved this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accrding to the [manual](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar/methods/Summary) it is not possible to change height with native function. You must use css.